Show the existence of pairwise distinct open subset for each distinct element in a Hausdorff space
I have a question that is as follows: Suppose that $x_1, x_2, ... ,x_n$ are distinct points in a Hausdorff space $X$. Show that there exist pairwise disjoint open subsets $U_1, U_2 , .. , U_k$ of $X$ such that $x_i \in U_i$ for every $i \in \{1, 2, ... , n\}$.
My solution is as follows:
Suppose for a contradiction that there does not exist such $U_1, U_2 , .. , U_k$. Then, there must be a pair of open subsets $U_m$ and $U_n$ such that $U_m \cap U_n \neq \emptyset$. However, this implies that either $x_m = x_n$, or that the Hausdorff condition does not hold. Hence, there is a contradiction.
The solution I found here for this question uses a different approach, hence why I am asking again. Is my proof wrong? If so, what needs ammending? Any feedback is appreciated!

If you use proof by contradiction, you need to state the correct negation.

@notime you are right! Thank you for pointing it out. I have changed the negation statement. However, I think it does not really affect my argument (?).

For the contradiction you begin by assuming there does not exist such subsets (indexed to $k,$ but should be to $n$ I think), and then you make a claim about two of the subsets. If such subsets do not exist, then how can you single out two of them?

$\neg$(There exist pairwise disjoint open subsets $U_1, U_2 , .. , U_n$ of $X$ such that $x_k \in U_i$ for every $i \in {1, 2, ... , n}$.)
$=$
(For any open subsets $U_1, U_2 , .. , U_n$ of $X$ such that $x_i\in U_i$ for every $i \in {1, 2, ... , n}$, there exists a pair of open sets $U_i$ and $U_j$ such that $U_i\cap U_j\neq \emptyset$.)

When $k>2$, $i$ and $j$ are not fixed.

You can use induction. For the case where there are two points, you just quote the Hausdorff condition. For the inductive step, you exploit the fact that a finite intersection of open sets is open.

First, the existence of two open intersecting neighborhoods does not violate the Hausdorff condition. For example, the entire space is an open neighborhood of any point.
Secondly, to negate an existential quantifier ("there does not exist x such that P(x)") you get a universal quantifier ("for every x we have ~P(x)"). So you do not have $U_m,U_n$ to consider by assumption.

For your answer, I don't see how to derive "$x_m=x_n$".
Let's consider the case where there are 3 points. Say $x,y,z$. By Hausdorff property, there exists $U_1,V_1$ that separates $x,y$;$U_2,V_2$ that separates $x,z$ ;$U_3,V_3$ that separates $y,z$ .Now take $U=U_1\bigcap U_2\bigcap U_3$ is enough, same for $V$ and $W$. This method can be used for $n\in \mathbb N$.
